# Bigquery - optimize query with count based filter

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a (working) query that filters a table based on the count of a given field grouped by another on the same table but it doesn't feel optimized.

`baseTable`

```
code,id,event
55d718,ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5,eventA
55d718,ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5,eventB
55d718,ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5,eventA
55d718,ABAjH0ggMvi-k5z8pbyR8_,eventA
98b1de,ABAjH0gkRy7s1enuFYGgzf,eventC
...
```

What I -conceptually- do is a "blacklist" of `id` used to filter `baseTable`: any line having a `id` contained in the blacklist should be filtered. The rule for entering the blacklist is **id count is more than 1 for a given code and the specific event `eventA`**.

`Expected result`

```
code, eventA (count), eventB (count), eventC (count)
55d718, 352, 18, 12
98b1de, 846, 78, 65
```

The expected result is a count of every event for all different code, but any `id` that appears more than 1 time for a given `code` and `event = eventA` (specifically `eventA` not the others) must be totally stripped out from the end result. In example data `ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5` has more than 1 line for code `55d718` and `eventA` so `filterTable` must not contain a single line that has `id = ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5` (even for other events).

Working (but sub-optimized) query :

```
WITH 

  baseTable as (select
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(cs_uri,r'code=([^&]*)') AS code,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(cs_uri,r'id=([^&]*)') AS id,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(cs_uri,r'event=([^&]*)') AS event
    from  `my-project.raw_data` 
    ),


  filteredTable as (SELECT *
  FROM baseTable
  where id = 'abcd' AND id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    id
  from baseTable where (event = 'eventA')  and code = 'abcd'
  group by id
  having count(id ) > 1  
 )
 )

  SELECT eventA , eventB from 
  (Select count(id) from filteredTable where event = 'eventA') as eventA,
  (Select count(id) from filteredTable where event = 'eventB') as eventB
  ... other queries on filteredTable
```

Every request I add on `filteredTable` adds the size of `baseTable` to the processed data, is there a better way?

A better (I think) query would be to directly set a `having code='XXXX'` in the `baseTable` since I don't really need querying several code as the same time, but the problem is I can't do this without `group by id, code, event` which makes it impossible to properly set the blacklist (since it's then not possible to get the count for `eventA`).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I would suggest that you write a trigger to split `cs_uri` into those components on insert/update. Using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` for every `SELECT` will get really slow as your table gets big.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff see my updated answer I hope it's enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't provide sample data and the number of rows in the original table, I can see only one optimization point for now.

You don't have to write subqueries in the last part. So you can change them to `count(case when condition then id end)`.
Also, since you want the output for each code, you should use a `group by code`

The other thing is, I think you're overfiltering the cases in filtered table. You shouldn't filter id column for abcd value as far as I could understand from your explanation.

So, you can use this code for the expected output. 
For example code, I changed your basetable code. So don't forget to change it to your original code with regex :)

```
WITH 
baseTable as (
  SELECT '55d718' AS code, 'ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5' as id,'eventA' as event UNION ALL
  SELECT '55d718' AS code, 'ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5' as id,'eventB' as event UNION ALL
  SELECT '55d718' AS code, 'ABAjH0j7yZmVBMhdDf4ab5' as id,'eventA' as event UNION ALL
  SELECT '55d718' AS code, 'ABAjH0ggMvi-k5z8pbyR8_' as id,'eventA' as event UNION ALL
  SELECT '98b1de' AS code, 'ABAjH0gkRy7s1enuFYGgzf' as id,'eventC' as event
),
blackList as (
  SELECT id
  from baseTable where (event = 'eventA')  and code = 'abcd'
  group by id
  having count(id ) > 1  
),
filteredTable as (
  SELECT baseTable.*
  FROM baseTable
  LEFT JOIN blackList USING (id)
  where blackList.id IS NULL
)
SELECT 
  code, 
  count(case when event='eventA' then id end) as eventA,
  count(case when event='eventB' then id end) as eventB
from filteredTable
group by code
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
with baseTable as ( 
      select REGEXP_EXTRACT(cs_uri,r'code=([^&]*)') AS code,
             REGEXP_EXTRACT(cs_uri,r'id=([^&]*)') AS id,
             REGEXP_EXTRACT(cs_uri,r'event=([^&]*)') AS event
      from  `my-project.raw_data` 
     )
select code, countif(event = 'eventA') as num_a,
       countif(event = 'eventB') as num_b
       countif(event = 'eventC') as num_c
from baseTable
group by code
having countif(event = 'eventA' and code = 'abcd') = 0;
```